# Permalink for external links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, permalinks

I would like to use permalink for external links on my site. For example, if I have this link on my site: `google.com`, it should rewrite to [and show the reader]:

```
mysite.com/go/google
```

Is this possible? Any ideas on how to go about doing this in .htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rewrite external urls. Rewriting doesn't look at your html code, it looks at the request sent to Apache, and pulls content based on your rewrite rule.